# How to activate websocket connection between Dataproc JupyterLab and python-lsp-server/python-language-server through component gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-dataproc, jupyter-extensions

It looks like the WebSocket connection between GCP Dataproc JupyterLab and LSP server (python-lsp-server) is blocked. Is there any way to customise initialisation actions on Dataproc cluster to forward this WebSocket connection to the gateway URL (or any other way to make the connection work)?

[JupyterLab WSS connection failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dch1M.png)

My Dataproc cluster is running fine using **2.0.45-debian10 image** with Jupyter as an additional component installed. The cluster automatically gives me the Component Gateway interface for JupyterLab, and the access is working fine with all kernels working.

I am now trying to activate the autocomplete/hinting on the JupyterLab notebook, with `softwareConfig.properties['dataproc:pip.packages']: 'jupyterlab-lsp==3.9.3,python-lsp-server==1.5.0'` properties added to initialise the cluster with the relevant lsp packages. Packages are working fine as well and the Dataproc correctly builds JupyterLab with the lsp activated.

But when I am trying to use the hinting in my JupyterLab notebook through component gateway, LSP server pane hangs at **initializing** and showing that the notebook is not connected to pyls/pylsp server. Chrome dev console shows that it is trying to connect to `wss://.../gateway/default/jupyter/lsp/ws/pyls` and connection drops.

I suspect this is because the lsp WebSocket connection is not forwarded through the component gateway - when I use SOCKS5 proxy to connect to the notebook using [cluster web interface instruction](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/cluster-web-interfaces), this works fine.

Any clue how this could work without me/team needing to make a manual SSH connection into the cluster?